# How to get a random row, using RedBeanPHP, from a table, that has gaps in id numbers order?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I'm trying to get a random row from a table using RedBean. I tried this:

```
$amount = R::count($names);
$id = rand(0, $amount);
$randomname = R::load( $names, $id );
$name = $randomname["name"];
```

But soon i found that this way is not correct, because the table has gaps in the id numbers order, there can be ids 1-95, then 115-523, then 530-600, etc. There are gaps, because i deleted rows manually, so the random $id falls on these gaps sometimes and never falls on last rows, because the $amount is smaller than the last id.

As i understand after trying to find the answer in others' questions, the id should be left untouched, that means i don't need to try to change the ids themselves so that they won't contain gaps. So i'm trying to make something instead.

I've tried also this, it works, though i think it's too many checks for a single row result:

```
$randomnames = R::findAll($names);
$a = 0;
foreach($randomnames as $n){
    if($a == $id){
        $name = $n['name'];
        $a = $amount;
    }
    else $a++;
}
```

Maybe i should use MySQL's RAND somehow, if there is nothing existing for this in RedBean itself, or R::exec with SQL... How is it the best to get a random row?

I've just started to learn both RedBean and PHP, tried to find an answer myself, also on RedBean's page, but couldn't find something specific for this. Also my first question here, so i hope i asked it correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents ;-)

```
$ids = R::getCol("select id from $names"); //returns an array of id's indexed as 0..number of names-1
$random_index = rand(0, sizeof($ids)-1);
$random_name = R::load( $names, $ids[$random_index] );
$name = $random_name["name"];
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it soon!